# Checkboxes are not displaying with bootstrap and knockoutjs binding

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

For some reason checkboxes are not being rendered next to my knockout bound labels

```
<div id="test">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[1]">
        <input id="1" type="checkbox" />
    </label>
</div>
```

View Model as follows:

```
var vm = {};
vm.repeatDayShortStr = ko.observableArray(["m","t","w","t","f","s","s"]);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2j9tgjr9/

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the solutions everyone the reason why I had the input inside the label was because it said so in the bootstrap example see the screenshot.

[image: Bootstrap Documentation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put `input` tag in a `label` tag.
try:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[1]"/>
<input id="1" type="checkbox" />
```

Since you're using `checkbox-inline` of `Bootstrap` it will decorate the inline part.

Also if you want the `input` to be associated with relative `label` you could use `for` attribute which takes the related input id:

```
<label for="1" class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[1]"/>
<input id="1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="2" class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[2]"/>
<input id="2" type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest doing this.

HTML

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'choiceTmpl', foreach: choices, templateOptions: { selections: selectedChoices } }"></div>

<script id="choiceTmpl" type="text/html">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: $data }, checked: $item.selections" />
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</script>
```

JS

```
var vm = {
    choices: ["m","t","w","t","f","s","s"],
    selectedChoices: ko.observableArray([])
};

vm.selectedChoicesDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    return this.selectedChoices().join(",");
}, vm);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Input` should not be in the `label` tag.

Try this:

```
<div id="test">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[1]"></label>
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[0]"></label>
    <input id="2" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[2]"></label>
    <input id="3" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[3]"></label>
    <input id="4" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[4]"></label>
    <input id="5" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[5]"></label>
    <input id="6" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="checkbox-inline" data-bind="text: repeatDayShortStr()[6]"></label>
    <input id="7" type="checkbox" /> 
</div>
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hdeLgnfy/1/)